# How to configure router to forward the SSH port to the NAS(Network attatched storage)?

Tags: networking

can any body help me to configure router to forward the SSH port to the NAS(Network attatched storage)?

Comment: duplicate - http://serverfault.com/questions/78251/how-to-configure-router-to-forward-the-ssh-port-to-the-nasnetwork-attatched-stor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming you're running a consumer-grade router, like the Linksys WRT54G family, you go to the admin page (http[s]://192.168.1.1 (or 0.1)), and click-through the option tabs until you get port-forwarding (should be "Port Range Forward" under 'Applications & Gaming').

Enter the incoming port ('Start') and target port ('End') along with the protocol (if needed), and the target IP of the NAS.

Save your configs, and you're good to go.

A longer example is available [here](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Linksys/WRT54G/default.htm).

Comment: Thanks a lot warren. It would really help. Thanks for your positive response.

Comment: happy to help :)